# Why Stripe Payment System is not working?

Tags: stripe-payments

i have implemented a payment system with stripe but when i connect with server then the server is crashed. Please answer the problem. I have created this code for payment system for my website.

My client site code-

```
   useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/create-payment-intent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ price })
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data?.clientSecret) {
                setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
            }
        })
}, [clientSecret, price])
```

my server site code-

```
app.post('/create-payment-intent', verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
            const service = req.body;
            const price = service.price;
            amount = price * 100;
            const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                amount: amount,
                currency: 'us',
                payment_method_types: ['card']
            });
            res.send({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret })
        })
```

error is coming-

```
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
  param: 'amount',
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Sun, 24 Jul 2022 12:43:34 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '240',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'idempotency-key': 'f17b3002-4ad7-4765-9442-3395630c3c3b',
    'original-request': 'req_7sXCHThynqnGhE',
    'request-id': 'req_7sXCHThynqnGhE',
    'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it means that the [`amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount) sent in the PaymentIntent Create request was not an integer.

I'd suggest logging into Stripe [dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/dashboard) and search the request ID `req_7sXCHThynqnGhE` in the search bar at the top to check `amount` value that you sent to Stripe.

Apart from `amount` value, the [`currency`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-currency) value in the request was also incorrect. It should be a three-letter ISO currency code in lowercase such as "usd".